# time Update of avatar image

Tags: php

because I have a image upload system for each user so that each user has their own profile picture, and hey it simply been controlling when you change an image the user must wait at least three minutes to return to change the image, in principle it works well I miss eh

```
if (  $tiempo >= $row['HoraAvatar']  || $row['HoraAvatar'] == "NULL" ) { 
    return true;             
} 
else { 
    return false; 
}
```

`$time` -> This variable contains the current time (24 hour format)
`$row ['HoraAvatar']` -> Time in which change by the image last time (24h format)

sensilla compared this works well ... but the problem is
that when the user changes his image at 12:59 PM and wants to switch to the 9:00 a.m. fails, because would be comparing

```
$time = 900;
$row ['HoraAvatar'] = 1259;
```

the condition `$time> = $row ['HoraAvatar']:` to return FALSE

Comment: You must compare date too, not only time. Probably easiest solution is to get modification file time with [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php), and compare it with current time to see the difference.

Comment: You should really compare timestamps, not integers representing hours.

Comment: can you try to do one example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a timestamp instead. A timestamp is the amount of seconds since a fixed point in time. If a user wants to change his image exactly 24 hours after the last time, your "HoraAvatar" would be exactly the same. A timestamp would be exactly 86400 bigger than your previous timestamp. You can do this with the `time()` function in php. ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php))

Comment: i dont know what do you try to said me

Comment: I am trying to say: "Use timestamps instead". The linked documentation provides you with information what `time()` does and you should be able to figure out how you can use it.